# input type number,listen to change even if string

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app i have the following:

```
<input  ng-name='{{quest.id}}'  type="number" class="form-control textInputBox inputMargin"
 ng-required='required' ng-model='$parent.input' >
```

and in my js:

```
scope.$watch('input', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
                    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                        if (scope.input || scope.input === 0) {
                            scope.quest.ans.valid = true;
                            scope.quest.ans.optVal = scope.input;
                        } else {
                            scope.quest.ans.valid = false;
                        }
                    }
                }, true);
```

All i want is to listen to a change even if the input from the user is not num, is it possible?
tried ng-changed and it's not working also...

The purpose of my input is not to prevent from typing string but to warn about it, and i still want to maintain it's input type='number'...

Comment: why don't you use `type="text"` along with `ng-pattern`?

Comment: What is the ng-pattern please..

Comment: it is a regex that the input should follow to see if it is valid or not

Comment: Check out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a suggestion. Try having a text input using a pattern:

```
<input ng-name='{{quest.id}}'  
       type="text" 
       class="form-control textInputBox inputMargin" 
       ng-required='required' 
       ng-model='$parent.input' >
```

then you may have in your watch:

```
scope.$watch('input', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        if ((scope.input || scope.input === 0) && !isNaN(newVal)) {
            scope.quest.ans.valid = true;
            scope.quest.ans.optVal = scope.input;
        } else {
            scope.quest.ans.valid = false;
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: I did exactly so, but if i do put some string in the box, the $watch is not working...!, it only works if there is a number, same as type=number which also allows me to enter string... so the behaviour is the same

Comment: Can you check my edit? I still have the type set to text, but now i check within the watch if the value is a number.